# PDO: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. But I have all the fields?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm having trouble with this insert statement. It is inside an if statement and used after a user successfully uploads and image.

```
                $contenido = $filename;
                $db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
                $data = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO publicaciones (autorID, autorNombre, nombre, claseDeContenido, contenido, palabras, etiquetas, fecha) VALUES (:autorID, :autorNombre, :nombre, :claseDeContenido, :contenido, :palabras, :etiquetas, :fecha)");
                $data->execute(array( ':autorID,' =>$autorID,
                            ':autorNombre' =>$autorNombre,
                            ':nombre' => $nombre,
                            ':claseDeContenido' => $claseDeContenido,
                            ':contenido' => $contenido,
                            ':palabras' =>$palabras,
                            ':etiquetas' => $etiquetas,
                            ':fecha' => $fecha));
```

The error is

```
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in .... on line 215
```

But there is no change of that variable name within the script, there are eight parameters to insert and I am sending 8. I have checked and **$fecha**, which is on line **215**, is definitely being sent.

What could it be?

None of this function is run without all fields being present in their respective variables.

```
if($autorID !== '' || $autorNombre !== '' || $nombre !== '' || $claseDeContenido !== '' || $contenido !== '' || $palabras !== '' || $etiquetas !== '' || $fecha !== '')
```

**NOTE:** The image is uploading succesfully

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a superfluous comma in the reference to `:autorID`:

```
                $data->execute(array( ':autorID,' =>$autorID,
//                                             ^--- remove this comma
```

Comment: How did I not see that. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
autorID,
```

is not defined

```
authorID
```

is, however.

You separate column names with commas but the comma can not be a part of the column name in the array you execute on the query.

Do this:

```
$data->execute(array( ':autorID' =>$autorID
```

instead of

```
$data->execute(array( ':autorID,' =>$autorID
```

And your code will run fine.

Answer (score 1):

> But I have all the fields?

You have not.

"parameter was not defined" means you are trying to bind a parameter that weren't defined in the query. So, you need to double check your query. Yourself. Without asking someone else to do it for you.